# Using Lagrange Multipliers to optimize a function

Tags: calculus

I am given a function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ restrained by $g(x,y)=8-\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2} =4$ and asked to use Lagrange multipliers to optimize it (I believe it refers to finding maxima or minima). However, when I used the method, all of the possible values either required that I use imaginary numbers or that I break the restraint.

The results I get are:

For $λ=0$, $$\Delta X=\frac{-\sqrt{(x^2+(y-1)^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lambda=0$$ $$\Delta Y=\frac{-y\sqrt{(x^2+(y-1)^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}*(y-1)}=\lambda=0$$
For $\lambda \neq0$, $$\frac{-\sqrt{(x^2+(y-1)^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{-y\sqrt{(x^2+(y-1)^2)}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}*(y-1)}$$

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Without LM easy to get that the maximum occurs for $(x,y)=(0,5)$ because the condition is an equation of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to solve the equivalent problem
$\min \{ x^2+y^2 | x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 16 \}$.

Note that the cost is continuous and the feasible set compact so the
extrema exist.

Lagrange gives
$x + \lambda  x = 0$, $y + \lambda (y-1) = 0$.

The first equation gives either $x=0$ or $\lambda = -1$. The
second equation gives $(1+\lambda)y = \lambda$. The second
equation eliminates $\lambda = -1$, hence we must have $x=0$.

The only $y$ values satisfying $(y-1)^2 = 16$ are $y = 1 \pm 4$ and
a
quick check shows that $y=-3$ yields a $\min$ and $y= 5$ yields a $\max$.

Comment: Thanks, I had that min from wolfram but I wasn´t sure how to get it, you really helped me.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Just a little thing, correct me if I made a mistake, but I think the signs on the 3rd line for both lambdas should be negative because they were positive on the other side of the =.

Comment: I don't follow, the two equations are $(1+\lambda)x = 0$ and $(1+\lambda)y -\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Oh, when I did the partial derivatives I got that x-λx=0 and y-λ(y-1)=0 so I got confused for a sec, but then I noticed that they are the same and give the same result. Sorry haha my bad.

Comment: Different folks use different conventions for multipliers, but the essential underlying result is that $\nabla f((x,y))$ and $\nabla g((x,y))$ are collinear.

Comment: I see, thank you mr. copper.hat, you have been very kind and helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange multipliers are not really necessary.

$f(x,y)$ is a cone with vertex at the orgin.

$g(x,y) = 4$ describes a cylinder with radius 4 and axis $(x,y) = 0,1$

and geometrically we can see where these intersect.

But you want to use Lagrange multipliers

$f(x,y,\lambda) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - \lambda (4-\sqrt {x^2 + (y-1)^2})$

But I am making life harder on myself than I need to.

Since $f(x,y) \ge 0$ if it maximized at some point, $f^2(x,y)$ will also be maximized at the same point.

Similarly we can find a simpler expression of the constraint.

$F(x,y,\lambda)= x^2 + y^2 - \lambda(16 - x^2 - (y-1)^2)\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} = 2x - 2\lambda x = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} = 2y - 2\lambda (y-1) = 0$

from the first equation $x = 0$ or $\lambda  = 1$

if $\lambda = 1, y - y + 1 = 0$ creating a contradiction.
$x = 0$

$(y-1)^2 = 16\\
y = 5,-3$

Comment: Thank you for the input, sorry if I made life harder on you, I was really lost on every single aspect of the problem.

Comment: You aren't making life hard, my point is that there are places to look to simplify these problems.  I considered solving this without the simplification.  the logic would have been identical but the notation a little messier.

Comment: I see, thanks for the help, I'll work on simplifying the problems, but for now, you saved my life.